# Float print gives extra numbers

Tags: c, printing, floating-point, atof

i am having a hard time printing float variable. It gives me extra numbers, that shouldn´t be there.
Here is example:

```
float number;
char temp[50];

fgets ( temp, sizeof temp, fr );  //reading string from file, example: 99.10   
number=atof(temp);

printf("%lf",number);             //console output: 99.101563
```

This is obviously wrong output. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: It's obviously correct, according to the spec.  Floating point is not an exact representation.

Comment: ... hunting for a dupe now.

Comment: "This is obviously wrong output" -- nope, this is actually correct output.

Comment: @MatthewRead This is as useful a characterization as “Integer is not an exact representation”. Binary floating-point is exact for values that lend themselves to that representation in the same way that integer types are.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Integers represent their *range* exactly; floats do not.  It's not useful to pretend that is not the relevant point of confusion.

Comment: @MatthewRead Integers do not represent 1.10 any better than floats do although it is in range for both, and this is completely relevant to the question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq No, 1.10 is not in the range of integers.  It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing unexpected about this output. `99.10` can't be represented exactly in IEEE754. Change your format to restrict output to two decimal places if that's what you want:

```
printf("%.2f", number);
```